# How to Show Voltage Inputs Without a Net in EAGLE

Tags: eaglecad, cad

when I am creating a schematic in EAGLE I would like the ability to show inputs from another area. I think this should be a possibility, as it is used widely. I have an example of an image below that I found (I didn't highlight) that shows what I am talking about. Look at DRAM_VREF for example. It's showing that the pin of the same name on the SoC should go to the 0.01UF capacitor, and then be grounded. Is thee any method for doing something similar in EAGLE? [image: Schematic Referencing Similar Topic]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes there is a way.
First you have to name all routes that are connected together with the same name, to do so click on the "rename" icon from the task bar and enter the name you would like to set. Then eagle will ask you if you would like to connect these routes and apply the new name, you should hit "YES" to do so.
This could connect all the routes that have the same name when converting to the board window, but to further enhance your schematic; you can lable routes from the "lable" icon on the task bar so that you can easily find each route name near the route itself. These steps will make your schematic looks like the one you have just attached.
Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

Add a supply voltage symbol from the parts library.
Connect the actual source for the supply to a symbol, and then at the place where you use it, add another supply symbol.